# Bootstrap resampling

Tags: confidence-interval, nonparametric, sample-size, bootstrap, resampling

I have a question with regard to non-parametric bootstrap re-sampling analysis.

I have a sample of n=200 values, and I have performed a bootstrap re-sampling creating 10.000 samples of the same n=200 and then calculated 95%CI, mean, st. deviation.

Can I perform the same bootstrap re-sampling creating 10.000 samples of different sizes (i.e. n=20, n=50, n=100, n=150) bootstrapped from the same original sample with n=200 values?

My objective is to see the impact of sample size (of my original training set) on the 95%CI, mean and st. deviation.

Comment: Have you taken a look at bootstrap theory? E.g., Davison and Hinkley (1997) Bootstrap Methods and Their Application. CUP.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions :) I am new to bootstrap analysis so I might be posting stupid questions, but  what is not clear to me is:
 If I can re-sample with replacement and create a number of bootstrap samples of the same size as my training set, why can't I use the same method (re-sample with replacement) and create bootstrap samples with varying size?
Thank you in advance
Maria

Comment: Well, you can create samples of varying sizes by resampling from the data with replacement, but that is called *bootstrap* only when resample size is equal to original sample size. Why do you want other sizes?